# How can I add handwritten notes to a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Is there any way to add handwritten notes to a Jupyter notebook? I've found [a picture](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5087930/38612196-79e8fa9a-3db8-11e8-95b4-5dcbf279aa78.jpg) describing what I want, but I can't seem to find a way to implement this into my notebook.

Answer (score 1):

The picture you linked is from a GitHub thread asking for that feature. If you scroll down the Issue/Feature request, then you'll find a link to [this extension](https://github.com/Calysto/notebook-extensions/tree/master/calysto/annotate) which enables this feature for you.

Comment: i wonder if there is a new tool, because the one you mentioned has the following  limitations:

lines go away when exiting annotation mode|
they only work on the current view; the window doesn't scroll|
there is no undo|
there are no shapes or text annotating|
no UI to control thickness of lines|
They could be saved in metadata.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure, maybe you should try searching by "extensions", since this one seemed to work fairly well for you